# Spark Parquet Perfomance with MapType Columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, parquet

I have a dataframe with more than 400 columns. Most of the columns are skewed i.e the values of most of columns in a row in the dataframe is mostly null except for few columns (about 20)

I am planning to change this structure to

```
col1:Array[String]
col2:Array[String]
...
MapColumn: MapType {
key:String
value:Array[String] 
}
```

I am wondering if there is a known performance impact using MapType column with parquet in spark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a few experiments to test the performance. I took a dataset with 100 columns and a million entry. I converted the dataset in MapType columns

```
Size of Parquet format all columns: 81MB
Size of Parquet format columns converted to MapType where map values could be NULL: 496MB
Size of Parquet format columns converted to MapType where map values with NULL removed: 86MB
```

Looks to me there is no significant difference if you can remove the Nulls.